# Take value of a variable from Jenkins before build and update it in config.properties

Tags: jenkins, build, continuous-integration, environment-variables, jenkins-plugins

My requirement is that I have a Jenkins Job which is parametrized and asks the Environment Variable Value in which my scripts need to run. On giving the value, jenkin should take that value and update it in config.properties file.

config.properties file:

```
ENVIRONMENT = ${env}
```

In Jenkins, I define my Global Parameters as:

> Global Variable String Parameter

Name: env

Default Value: SIT1

(Couldn't post image due to low reputation)

So, when I click on build now, it asks for value for variable env, and starts execution. However, it throws error as the environment variable in config.properties doesn't  identify the value provided before build.

P.S- I have  **EnvInject Plugin** installed, if that can help, then please do guide me how to make use of it. If my question seems confusing, kindly suggest the points I can provide to make it simple.

Comment: so, if I understood correctly, you cannot pass an environment variable that you set in Jenkins, to your script. You set it up in global parameter but you can't pass it to the script, correct?

Comment: I am pretty new to Jenkins, so I can't say it's possible or not. However, my requirement is same as that you are saying. I want value of an environment variable in Jenkins to be pass to my script(config.properties). If it is not possible, kindly suggest me any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I'm not sure if you really can "inject" the environment variable to the script. Some time ago I wrote a plugin for Jenkins that had to deal with some perl scripts and was really hard back then to deal with environment variable.

About EnvInject Plugin I can't say almost anything, I never used. What you can try, for example, is to use the "build-action" option to run shell or batch commands. You can set the environment variable:
In batch `set VARIABLE=value` or `export VARIABLE=value` for shell. Then, in your script you can get the value of the variable really easy.

This is somehow the easy and safe method to pass some variables to a script.

I'm really not sure, it's almost 3 months since I didn't touch Jenkins, if those global properties are not really for passing them to scripts. Your script ran on your PC, so, if it'll use an environment variable, those has to be set. To pass the variables that you set in Jenkins, it'll need to set/export them on your machine and I'm not sure if that plugin have that implemented.

Tell me if it worked, and I'll try to find a solution! Keep in touch!

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I have used your idea and I am using following command in 'JVM options' under 'Build' Menu in Jenkins -DargLine="-Denv=$Environment", where $Environment value is asked by user before build. In my scripts, I am fetching this value by command 'ENV=System.getProperty("env");'. Thanks again for showing me the way :)